# jQuery Datepicker does not work when loading a page for second time with ajax request ($.load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datepicker

First of all, I use asp.net but for this case does not matter because I am not use asp elements, only basic html elements and jQuery.

I have initialized a jQuery datepicker in my default.aspx page in the function loadDatepicker. This page have one button element which call the function loadWorkSpace which use $.load method to load a form page (called form.aspx), which use a datepicker, and this page is loaded in a specific div element of the default.aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function loadDatepicker() {
         $.getScript("/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js").done(
                            function () {
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                                    showOn: "button",
                                    buttonImage: "/resources/img/calendar.png",
                                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                                    buttonText: "",
                                }).attr("readonly", "true");
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "today");
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "firstDay", 1)
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "monthNames", ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]);
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "monthNamesShort", ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"]);
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dayNames", ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado"]);
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dayNamesMin", ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa"]);
                            }
         );
     }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function loadWorkSpace(pagina) {
        $("#workSpace").load(pagina, function () { loadDatepicker() });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the button, and it calls to the function loadWorkSpace, the first time the datepicker works when I click on the icon trigger! But the second time that I click on the button the datepicker shows in the input element the default value which I put in the option "setDate" of datepicker which the correct format, but when I click in the icon trigger to show datepicker, this does not work...

Can someone tell me my mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you reload your HTML your DOM elements are new ones with no events assigned.

You need to either re-assign the events or use something like `on` or `live`.

Of course that may mean you needing to do some modification to whatever script you are using to setup the events in the first place!

This is why I like coding my own jQuery controls.